# Finding out if string contains string, and splitting it if it does

Tags: php, string

I want to figure out if a string contains more then 1 occurance of `http://`

Like this:

```
http://uploading.com/files/c8e99378/image-slider-skins.zip/http://www.filesonic.com/file/3524497744/image-slider-skins.zip
```

I know how to find out if it does, but how do I split the string at the begining of the second `http`?

Comment: With `strrpos` and `substr`. Or simpler: a regex looking for the first occurence and stripping until there.

Comment: @mario a REGEX simpler? Please no. It's slower and really not made of tasks as this one

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode('http://', $str);
$secondPart = 'http://'.$parts[2];

echo $secondPart;
```

More information in the documentation of [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)

---

Or some other method (which is simpler and properbly faster):

```
$firstPart = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'http://', 8));
```

---

Or you can also use a REGEX which I don't recommend, because it's to heavy for this simple task:

```
if (preg_match('/(http:\/\/.*)(?=http:\/\/)/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Ty, looking in to explode now

Comment: The explode (totally overused) approach results in three parts. And yes, three lines of code are more effort than one (regex).

Comment: @mario more effort to type, but less time to render... (however, there are just 2 lines...)  I've also added a second example, which is just one line and maybe the fastest option.

Comment: @mario to make you happy, I also added a REGEX example

Comment: For small strings, yes.  Also I'm very happy. (But btw, I believe OP may have wanted to extract the second URL.)

Comment: Yes OP wanted that hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/explode)

```
$parts = explode('http://', $string);
```

You can also directly fetch parts of the result into variables:

```
list($part1, $part2) = explode('http://', $string);
```

Comment: It'll be three parts with the whacky explode approach, the first being an empty string.